# linked list insert in order and memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list

Inside a function for linked list:

```
// nodePtr is a pointer to a struct
// list is a pointer to the linked list
nodePtr *current = list;

[some manipulation using *current here...]

// insert new node in front of *current node
nodePtr temp = *current;
*current = createNode(value);
(*current)->next = temp;
```

Because temp is not a direct pointer so when I assigned (*current)->next back to temp, will it creates a copy in the heap? And then the original memory now has no pointer to it and leaked?

I was trying to setup an insert function for a linked list that insert the node in order (a member in struct to check the value) so it requires no sorting.

Comment: Oh, this code is misleading.  Please don't hide pointer types behind `typedefs`!

Answer (score 0):

> will it creates a copy in the heap?

When you assign one pointer to another, no additional memory is allocated on the heap.

Comment: @SayemAhmed: I don't think so. The code is confusing, but it does state "nodePtr is a *pointer* to a struct" in a comment.

Comment: Yup, I have also seen it just now. Pretty confusing after all.

Answer (score 0):

If `nodePtr` is a pointer to a struct(I assume you typedef nodePtr), then  you have defined current as a pointer to pointer to a struct. `Current has to be initialised with a pointer to type nodePtr not a pointer to the struct.`

```
nodePtr current = list //this should work
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nodePtr temp;
```

This line assigns memory for 'temp' variable in stack(not heap). It is just a pointer variable which can store address of a structure which you have typedef'd somewhere.

Also, there will be no leakage in this code. You, perhaps, allocated memory for creating new node and it is getting stored in (*current)->next.

As nodePtr is already a pointer type,  *current*  is a double pointer. So I think, this is incompatible

```
nodePtr *current = list;
```

It should be something like

```
nodePtr *current = &list;
```